# creating bar plot with 2 quantities in each column

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart, multiple-columns

I would like to create a bar plot using the below information. I would like it to be divided between the top row and absent/present. I've tried bar plot and ggplot but they come up with errors or incorrect information. Thanks!

```
    LHUM    RHUM    LRAD    RRAD    LFEM    RFEM    LTIB    RTIB
    present absent  present absent  present present absent  present
    present present absent  present present present present present
    present present present present present present present present
    present present present present present present present present
    present present present present present present present present
    present present present present present present present present
    present present present absent  present present present present
    present present absent  present present present present present
    present present absent  present present present present present
    present present present absent  present present present present
    present present present absent  present present present present
    present absent  present absent  present present present present
    present present present absent  present present present present
    present present present present present absent  present absent
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I'm not 100% sure what you want.   Maybe this - assuming that your data is in a dataframe called  `df`

First reshape it to ggplot longform format using `tidyr`.   Then plot...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- df %>% gather(name,value,1:8)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(name, color=value, fill=value)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]